# Probe returning: From which mineral field it gathered resources?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

If I have a Probe returning with minerals back to the base (Issued order "ProbeHarvest",1), how do I know where it was mining from?
I would like to write a trigger which orders the probe to return back to the mineral field early.

To clarify: I have a trigger whose action is one of those:

- order to return resources back to Nexus:

  `TriggerAddEventUnitOrder(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1)`
- used an ability to return resources back to Nexus:

  `TriggerAddEventUnitAbility(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, c_abilHarvestStageApproachDropOff, false)`

and in the trigger action I want to learn were it was mining from.

Note: I know how learn when the probe is *approaching* the mineral field  `TriggerAddEventUnitOrder(null, "ProbeHarvest", 0)`, but I don't need that information *at that time*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - the gather resources ability is divided into several phases, each can be used as a trigger event. You don't need to check the *orders*, but only what the unit is actually doing.

- `TriggerAddEventUnitAbility(null, "ProbeHarvest", 0, ApproachDropOffHarvest)` - unit is aproaching the mineral field for harvesting
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 0, WaitatResourceHarvest)` - unit reached the resource node and started waiting at it (maybe another unit is harvesting here already?). This is triggered even if no actual waiting is needed (it waits for 0 seconds).
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 0, HarvestHarvest)` - the unit is at the resource node and started harvesting
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, WaittoReturnHarvest)` - unit finished gathering resources. After this event there is usually a short period of time when the probe sits idle at the mineral field with the gathered resources.
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, ApproachDropOffHarvest)` - the unit started approaching the drop-off building (Nexus)
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, WaitforDropOffHarveset)` - the unit reached the drop-off building and started waiting at it. In the basic game mechanic there is no waiting time every, but this is always triggered anyway. You could imagine a custom game where one harvester cannot return resources when another is currently doing so.
- `...(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, DropOffHarveset)` - the unit is dropping off the gathered resources into the player's bank.

For the events marked as `"ProbeHarvest", 0` you can learn which mineral field it is approaching directly through `EventUnitTargetTunit()`. For `"ProbeHarvest", 1` (unit returning) however, that function would give you back the drop-off building unit instead.

What you can do is that when harvesting begins (`HarvestHarvest`), you store the target mineral field unit in a custom "field" of your probe, and then retrieve the information in the next trigger when you return.

For creating custom fields you can check this answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/192794/92581

With that solution you would have:

```
(Trigger)
onStartGettingResources
    Events
        TriggerAddEventUnitAbility(null, "ProbeHarvest", 0, c_abilHarvestStageHarvest, false)
    Local Variables
        minerals <unit>
             EventUnitTargetUnit()
    Actions
        StoreUnitWithUnit(EventUnit(), "miningFrom", minerals)

(Trigger)
onStartReturningResources
    Events
        TriggerAddEventUnitAbility(null, "ProbeHarvest", 1, c_abilHarvestStageApproachDropOff, false)
    Local Variables
        minerals <unit>
            GetUnitWithUnit(EventUnit(), "miningFrom")
    Actions
        //use the "minerals"
```

Where `StoreUnitWithUnit` and `GetUnitWithUnit` are the counterparts of getters/setters for custom fields, working with units rather than integers.

Note that this can still cause errors when the mineral field the probe harvested from got depleted.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read up on [Units](http://www.galaxywiki.net/Units) (anything you can click on). Each unit has an ID.

Next, you will have to use a [trigger](http://www.galaxywiki.net/Trigger). When a harvester starts to harvest from a mineral patch, you will make a trigger that assigns that harvester to the mineral patch.

You can learn the basics of triggers [here](http://www.galaxywiki.net/Trigger_Basics).

So once a probe starts harvesting, you can trigger a countdown or whatever you have in mind. Then in that trigger you will command it to go back to the ID it just harvested from which can be found from the resources it is currently gathering or the X/Y axis on the map (I'm also assuming there are other ways to get the ID of what it came from)

Comment: Having a trigger on *start* mining, and then having a `wait` until harvesting is done is error prone. What if harvesting was interrupted for some reason (e.g. from player input)? I need a trigger when the mining has *finished*, but then I don't know how to get the ID of the mineral patch unit that it was mining from.