# Custom variables/fields for units?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

Is there a way to associate new/custom variables with units?

There are two triggers I want to apply on a unit.

- First trigger, invoked on a unit, should check the current order assigned to it and remember the order target (of type `unit` or `integer` (unit ID))
- Second trigger occuring on the same unit should recall the value, and do something with it. But when the second trigger occurs, the old order does not exist anymore.

There is `UnitSetCustomValue`, but this one works on `Real` types and not `int` or `unit`. I cannot store unit-ID in it because I lose precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data Tables using the unit tags to "create" and manage arbitrary fields.

- Data Table - is a `String -> Any` hashmap. You can store any value of built-in type in it.

  There is one `global` and one `local` data table. You need the global one to make the values persistent.
- Unit Tag - is a unique ID integer associated with each unit

So, if you want a custom field "FooBar" associated with a unit with given ID, you can store "{ID}FooBar" in the data table, and later retrieve it. Consider using helper functions/actions to manage that:

```
(Action Definition)
StoreIntWithUnit
    Parameters
        owner <unit>
        fieldname <string>
        value <int>
    Local Variables
        ID = <int> UnitGetTag(owner)
    Actions
        DataTableSetInt(true, CombineString(IntToString(ID), fieldname), value)

(Function Definition)
GetIntWithUnit
    Return Type: <int>
    Parameters
        owner <unit>
        fieldname <string>
    Local Variables
        ID = <int> UnitGetTag(owner)
    Actions
        Return( DataTableGetInt(true, CombineStrings(IntToString(ID), fieldname) )
```

Similar set of getters/setters can be defined for other types, e.g. units.

It's not the fastest way to achieve it, but it works. It would be great that when a unit is destroyed, you delete the no longer needed entries; otherwise you get a memory leak.